# Totalling a multiple Datediff columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I hope you can help, I need to total the TotalCapacity column to give me a years total based of the Where Statement. I will also need to see different years next to each other. Thanks

```
SELECT
    Capacity.StartDate,
    Capacity.EndDate,
    DATEDIFF(d, Capacity.StartDate, Capacity.EndDate) + 1 AS DaysOpen,
    Capacity.Capacity,
    (DATEDIFF(d, Capacity.StartDate, Capacity.EndDate) + 1) * Capacity.Capacity AS TotalCapacity,
FROM
    Capacity
WHERE 
    Capacity.StartDate >= '01 Jan 2010' 
    AND Capacity.EndDate <= '31 Dec 2010'
```

Comment: Do you get some kind of error or what?

Comment: No, I just want to a total of all the rows where the column says Total Capacity.

Comment: Hi Andrey

I have 882 rows that have a Total Capacity, I need to total all 882 rows so I get a grand total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you need some kind of this:

```
SELECT SUM(TotalCapacity)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
          Capacity.StartDate
          ,Capacity.EndDate
          ,DATEDIFF(d, Capacity.StartDate, Capacity.EndDate) + 1 AS DaysOpen
          ,Capacity.Capacity
          ,(DATEDIFF(d, Capacity.StartDate, Capacity.EndDate) + 1) * Capacity.Capacity AS TotalCapacity
        FROM
          Capacity
          WHERE Capacity.StartDate >= '01 Jan 2010' AND Capacity.EndDate <= '31 Dec 2010'
    ) t
```